# CSS - Overflow scrolling not working

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup (see my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/boUXMANMiTC2HjmHjKkG?p=preview)):

```
<div class="workflow-step-container">
  <div class="step-container">
      <div class="step-bubble completed">1</div>
      <span class="divider"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="step-container">
      <div class="step-bubble completed">2</div>
      <span class="divider"></span>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

The number of steps (bubbles) can vary.  What I would like to happen is if the number of bubbles exceeds the container width, I would like the bubble container to become horizontally scrollable.  Currently, the content just wraps.

I've added `overflow-x: auto;`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance

**Update**
After adding `white-space:nowrap;` to my `.workflow-step-container` styles, the bubbles now do not wrap as desired.  In my actual project, though, the content continues to wrap and doesn't ever become scrollable.  [Here](http://s12.postimg.org/5aedat7hp/Capture.png) is a screenshot.  I tried wrapping the `.workflow-step-container` div in another div to which I set `overflow-x: hidden;`, but that did nothing.  Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/H9o97NWZrdKFtsSTskhW?p=preview).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply change the [`white-space` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) of the parent element to `nowrap` in order to prevent the inline-level elements from wrapping. In doing so, a horizontal scrollbar will be added when content overflows.

[**Updated Example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/T13Krzxfa56jBje4jkkr?p=preview)

```
.workflow-step-container {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

---

Based on your update, you need to add `table-layout: fixed`/`width: 100%` to the nested ancestor `table` element.

The problem was that the `table` element's width was being determined by the maximum width of the `.workflow-step-container` element. Adding a width of `100%` forces the parent element to take the width of its parent element, and `table-layout: fixed` changes the layout algorithm to allow for this.

[**Updated Example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/cKAty5KO2ZmpnValHSob?p=preview)

```
.col-xs-8 table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @im1dermike Do you have a link demonstrating it not working? I'll take a look. It is probably related to an ancestor element's width.

Comment: @JoshCrozier: Nevermind.  I was able to re-create it.  http://plnkr.co/edit/H9o97NWZrdKFtsSTskhW?p=preview Seems like it has to do with being inside a table.

Comment: @im1dermike Updated my answer - http://plnkr.co/edit/cKAty5KO2ZmpnValHSob?p=preview